# how to add a line break in node-js?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-lex

I am trying to add a line break in between two strings in node js inside a lambda function.

I have tried using '\n' , '\r\n' and also tried importing os and then using os.EOL statement, but none of these worked.

```
------------------------Using '\n'-------------------------------

var msg = `The order(s) for the customer ${CustomerNumber} and its status are ${data}`
msg+='\n'
msg+= ' To know the order details of another customer enter the customer 


-------------------------- Using '\r\n' -------------------------------
var msg = `The order(s) for the customer ${CustomerNumber} and its status are ${data}`
msg+='\n'
msg+= ' To know the order details of another customer enter the customer number'

-------------------------- Using 'os.EOL' -------------------------------
var os = require("os");
var msg = `The order(s) for the customer ${CustomerNumber} and its status are ${data}`+os.EOL+' To know the order details of another customer enter the customer number'


-------------- Sending msg string to the AWS lex bot----------------------
callback(elicitSlot(sessionAttributes, deliveryStatus, slots, "CustomerNumber", {

                        'contentType': 'PlainText',
                        'content': msg

                    } ));

function elicitSlot(sessionAttributes, intentName, slots, slotToElicit, message) {
    return {
        sessionAttributes,
        dialogAction: {
            type: 'ElicitSlot',
            intentName,
            slots,
            slotToElicit,
            message,
        },
    };
}
```

all these had node effect, and the output i got was without a line break and as a continuous string

The output which i am expecting is: "The order(s) for the customer abcd and its status are 1234, 5678, 9876 "
To know the order details of another customer enter the customer number'

Output what i am getting is: "The order(s) for the customer abcd and its status are 1234, 5678, 9876 " To know the order details of another customer enter the customer number'

I think it is because i am giving the content type as 'plain text', can anyone suggest me a solution?

Comment: Please specify how you output your data. To a terminal \n should work. To a file os.EOL would be good. For html you have to replace your \n with a break (<br>), specify in the css that the browser should respect your linebreaks or wrap it in a <pre> or alike statement.

Comment: Actually the output data is getting sent to a chatbot in AWS Lex

Comment: Did you try `\\n`?

Comment: In that case it depends on your output channel. In Facebook or Slack \n works. You have to view the output in your final output channel to test.

Comment: Did you do simple, 
msg =\`line1<press enter>
line2`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bit old but I found the answer to this in a [tutorial](https://medium.com/leclevietnam/aws-cognito-send-custom-email-784ff7059977). To use html inside of your message you need to use backticks for the message. For instance:

```
event.response.emailMessage = `<h1>Welcome to the App!</h1> <p>Your user name is ` + event.request.usernameParameter + `</p> <p>Your temporary password: ` + event.request.codeParameter + `</p> <p>If you need assistance, please contact the help desk at (555) 555-5555 or email <a href="mailto:help@example.org">help@example.org.</a></p>`;
```

Hopefully this will help someone else out.